# How to use a Dynamic Variable to access Scope field - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope, angularjs-scope

I am trying to have a variable string, and access the matching $scope.field but it is undefined and not  returning what I am expecting. What am I doing wrong, or is this not possible?

```
$scope.selectedHolidayA = "Christmas"
$scope.selectedHolidayB = "NewYears"

var HA = "selectedHolidayA";
var HB = "selectedHolidayB";
```

I want to get the same result as $scope.selectedHolidayA = "Christmas". But I am getting undefined.

I tried these but no luck.

```
console.log("Test 1", $scope["HA"]);   //I want these to return "Christmas"
console.log("Test 2", $scope[HA]);     //Currently returns undefined
console.log("Test 3", $scope.HA);
```

Is it possible to pass variables, if so how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use "Test 2":

```js
$scope = {};

$scope.selectedHolidayA = "Christmas"
$scope.selectedHolidayB = "NewYears"

var HA = "selectedHolidayA";
var HB = "selectedHolidayB";

console.log($scope[HA]+' and '+$scope[HB]);

console.log("Test 2", $scope[HA]);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks! The example I actually tried originally didn't have HA with quotations marks, so it was undefined. It was var HA = selectedHolidayA;  before by mistake.